# How to search using the Citrix ShareFile API

Tags: json, api, rest, citrix

I am using the Sharefile REST API for a project and have run into an issue.  Their documentation is lacking and so far my 5 emails to the api@ address have gone unanswered.  Figured I would crowdsource this one...

What I need to do is search for a file by its name and it also has to have a specific parentID.  I am following their documentation as best I can, but I still get a 500 error on the response.

According to their API [documentation](http://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=Items) I have to post to: `https://account.sf-api.com/sf/v3/Items/AdvancedSimpleSearch` with the following post:

```
{ 
    "Query":{ 
        "AuthID":"", 
        "ItemType":"", 
        "ParentID":"", 
        "CreatorID":"", 
        "LuceneQuery":"", 
        "SearchQuery":"", 
        "CreateStartDate":"", 
        "CreateEndDate":"", 
        "ItemNameOnly":"", 
    }, 
    "Paging":{ 
        "Key":"", 
        "PageNumber":1, 
        "PageSize":10, 
    }, 
    "Sort":{ 
        "SortBy":"", 
        "Ascending":false, 
    }, 
    "TimeoutInSeconds":10 
}
```

The JSON post I am sending looks like this:

```
{
    "Query": {
        "AuthID": "",
        "ItemType": "",
        "ParentID": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CreatorID": "",
        "LuceneQuery": "",
        "SearchQuery": "filename ='foo.png'",
        "CreateStartDate": "4/2/2014",
        "CreateEndDate": "4/4/2014",
        "ItemNameOnly": ""
    },
    "Paging": {
        "Key": "",
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "PageSize": 10
    },
    "Sort": {
        "SortBy": "",
            "Ascending": false
        },
    "TimeoutInSeconds": 10
}
```

They prefilled some properties in their example post so I replicated.  I did also try sending only what I needed too (instead of the blank properties) but still get a 500.

I can upload files, delete, modify, etc all fine with no issues so I am certain it is something in this JSON structure.  I think it comes down to the "SearchQuery" property. There is zero examples on their documentation site, and any libraries that were made 3rd party only show a "query" parameter being passed in with no example of what that looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    {
    "Query": {
        "AuthID": "",
        "ItemType": "",
        "ParentID": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CreatorID": "",
        "LuceneQuery": "",
        "SearchQuery": "foo.png",
        "CreateStartDate": "4/2/2014",
        "CreateEndDate": "4/4/2014",
        "ItemNameOnly": ""
    },
    "Paging": {
        "Key": "",
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "PageSize": 10
    },
    "Sort": {
        "SortBy": "",
            "Ascending": false
        },
    "TimeoutInSeconds": 10
}
```

In searchQuery we have to specify item name itself instead of filename='itemname'. Working for me :)

Answer (score -1):

I've been trying to wrestle with this too.  I am using the HTTPS API and not the REST API, but maybe the same argument will work?  My client has specified PHP so looking at Sharefile's PHP sample code sharefile.php - you will see a search function with a "$query" parameter.  After a few attempts I tried supplying this argument: '{Name="Agreements"}'.  I think you might be able to generalize to more complicated searches.  The PHP sample code does a http_build_query to convert the above to the usual HTML parameter string.

Comment: Tried a few more things and instead of an "=" in the middle of the argument a space works, a colon works.  It looks like the text match is of the sort as in MySQL LIKE %Agreements% - it just looks for the occurrence of the supplied text as a substring of the field.