# Using the Citrix ShareFile API, how can I get the most recently uploaded files?

Tags: rest, citrix, sharefile

I'd like to run a job once or twice an hour to retrieve any files that have been uploaded to our client's root folder. That will include files nested 2 or 3 folders deep.

Currently our client is having someone manually run a report through the dashboard interface once an hour to generate a CSV file listing them. It's very cumbersome.

After a bit of Googling and sniffing around the [ShareFile API docs](https://api.sharefile.com/rest/), the best idea I have is to use the [Items resource](https://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=Items). Specifically, I'm planning to take advantage of the `CreateStartDate` field in the advanced search query interface:

- http://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=ShareFile.Api.Models.Query

I've got my API key and I'm about to start doing some tests (using Ruby for a Rails app). As I do, I thought I'd ask here to see if there was a more direct or efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Ruby code (within a Rails app) that returns files posted to an account's home folder within the last hour.

Note the secrets required. I was disappointed to have to include a user name and password.

```
class ShareFileService
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://YOUR-SUBDOMAIN.sharefile.com'
  attr_reader :auth_token, :response

  def initialize; end

  def authenticate
    return @auth_token if @auth_token.present?

    api_endpoint = '/oauth/token'
    params = {
      'grant_type'    => 'password',
      'client_id'     => Rails.application.secrets.sharefile_client_id,
      'client_secret' => Rails.application.secrets.sharefile_client_secret,
      'username'      => Rails.application.secrets.sharefile_user,
      'password'      => Rails.application.secrets.sharefile_pass
    }
    body = { body: params }
    @response = self.class.post(api_endpoint, body)

    # This is the auth token
    @auth_token = JSON.parse(@response.body)
    @auth_token
  end

  def home_folder
    # https://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=Items
    # "Returns: home folder for current user"
    token = authenticate
    api_uri = format('https://%s.sf-api.com/sf/v3/Items', token['subdomain'])
    auth_header = format('Bearer %s', token['access_token'])

    headers = { 'authorization' => auth_header }
    params = { '$expand' => 'Children' }
    options = {
      headers: headers,
      query: params
    }
    @response = self.class.get(api_uri, options)

    JSON.parse(@response.body)
  end

  def recent_files
    # http://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=Items#Advanced_Simple_Search
    # "Returns: home folder for current user"
    token = authenticate
    api_uri = format('https://%s.sf-api.com/sf/v3/Items/AdvancedSimpleSearch', token['subdomain'])
    auth_header = format('Bearer %s', token['access_token'])
    an_hour_ago = (Time.zone.now - 1.hour).iso8601

    # Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565283/9381758
    params = {
      'Query': {
        'ItemType': '',
        'ParentID': '',
        'CreatorID': '',
        'SearchQuery': '',
        'CreateStartDate': an_hour_ago,
        'CreateEndDate': '',
        'ItemNameOnly': false
      },
      'Paging': {
        'Count': 100,
        'Skip': 0
      },
      'Sort': {
        'SortBy': 'CreateStartDate',
        'Ascending': false
      },
      'TimeoutInSeconds': 10
    }
    options = {
      headers: { 'authorization' => auth_header },
      body: params
    }
    @response = self.class.post(api_uri, options)

    JSON.parse(@response.body)
  end
end
```

Sample usage:

```
$ rails console
> sharefile = ShareFileService.new
> body = sharefile.recent_files
=> {"PartialResults"=>false, "Results"=> ...}
> body.keys
=> ["PartialResults", "Results", "TimedOut", "odata.metadata", "odata.type", "url"]  
> body['PartialResults']
=> false
> body['Results'].length 
=> 100
```